# 'System.InvalidProgramException' in System.Net.Http.dll c#

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, asp.net-web-api, system.net

Tests in my unit test project which are written for WebApi's are failing.

The Exception that is thrown is 'System.InvalidProgramException' in System.Net.Http.dll 
Additional information: Common Language Runtime detected an invalid program.

This is thrown while initializing the request object of controller to use in tests:

```
        this.samplecontroller.Request = new HttpRequestMessage() { Properties = { { HttpPropertyKeys.HttpConfigurationKey, new HttpConfiguration() } } };
```

I'm struggling with this problem, any help would be greatly appreciated.

The .Net Framework i use is 4.6.1

Comment: Can you share the code which you are trying to unit test along with the complete unit test code?